# Can we pull down the configuration from MDM server?

Tags: iphone, mdm, udid

How can I update my webservice (server information) via mdm in the app. Now server information stored as a separate setting.plist file in the app directory. I want to update this info.

Comment: Can you use Push Notification to send updated server information from server to application of device?

Comment: We can send the configuration from server but how does it updates the settings.plist file?, should we write any code for that?

Comment: I don't know any way that will allow you change settings without additional coding. And are you looking for a way without any coding?

Comment: Yes. Could you please explain the same? How can we do it?
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: I don't know any way to do what you want to do without any coding. Ability to change settings should be implemented in the applications. iOS doesn't provide any way to change content of settings file inside application.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to follow the guidelines set by the "Managed App Configuration" in the Mobile Device Management protocol, or your selected MDM will have to cooperate—most major MDMs support this.

The configuration will be in the com.apple.configuration.managed key under NSUserDefaults.
Not in a separate plist.

Configuration changes will trigger NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification.

Apple has an example code-base "ManagedAppConfig" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2279/Introduction/Intro.html which implements this.